# Redirect domain1 to domain2 with path after slash

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, joomla

I have 2 domain

domain1.com
domain2.net

i want redirect domain1.com to domain2.net with path alias after slash, like this

domain1.com/joomla(this is folder)/path-to-content >>> domain2.net/joomla(this is folder)/path-to-content

i used this rule but didn't work with path after slash

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ http://www.domain.net/persian/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This rule works like this

domain1.com/joomla(this is folder)/path-to-content >> domain2.net/joomla(this is folder)

my server is centos 6.2 and apache and content management system is Joomla.

Comment: The `$1` in your rule is back referencing only a slash, if exists. Replace `(/)?$` with `(.*)$` and see what happens. That is, if I understood right.

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA if i use index.php it works fine but if remove index.php it didn't work  - like this `domain1.com/joomla(this is folder)/index.php/path-to-content >> domain2.net/joomla(this is folder)/index.php/path-to-content` i want to work it witout index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use a domain alias, or let the domains share the same docroot (if the content on both domains is to be identical) in your hosting control panel.

Answer (score 0):

you said you want to REDIRECT to domain2.net. instead of the rewrite condition you could use a simple `redirect` to achieve an equal result. add this code to the .htaccess file in the public_html directory of domain1.com:

```
redirect / http://domain2.net/
```